# what does this jcl error code mean? can't figure out what i need to fix

Tags: zos, jcl

I'm getting an error code of 452 and in the stmt no message it says "IEFC0061 Positional parameters must be specified before keyword parame"
I just can't seem to find where exactly this error is. Can someone take a look at my code and help? thanks!

```
//TSOZA60  JOB 3ES10G10000012,'TSOZA60',MSGCLASS=Q,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),
//         NOTIFY=&SYSUID,CLASS=A,REGION=2M
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY
//IN       DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=D80WW.ES10V15.CNTL
//OUT      DD   DISP=OLD,DSN=TSOZA60.COPY.CNTL
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD   *
    COPY OUTDD=OUT,INDD=IN
    SELECT MEMBER=((JOBCARD,,R))
/*
```

```
22.58.38 JOB19239 IEFC452I TSOZA603 — JOB NOT RUN — JCL ERROR 452   ------ JES2 JOB STATISTICS ------
    12 CARDS READ 
    23 SYSOUT PRINT RECORDS 
     0 SYSOUT PUNCH RECORDS 
     1 SYSOUT SPOOL KBYTES 
  0.00 MINUTES EXECUTION TIME 

1 //TSOZA603 JOB 3ES10610000012,sTSOZA60$,MSGCLASS=Q,MSGLEVEL(1,1), 
  //         NOTIFY=&SYSUID,CLASS=A,REGION=2M 
  IEFC653I SUBSTITUTION JCL — 3E S10610000012,sTSOZA60$,MSGCLASS=Q,MSGLEV 
2 //STEP1 EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY 
3 //IN DD DISP=SHR,DSN=080WW.ES10V15.CNTL 
4 //OUT DD DISP=SHR,DSN=TSOZA60.COPY.CNTL 
5 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=* 
6 //SYSIN DD * 
7 //SYSIN DD *            GENERATED STATEMENT 
STMT NO. MESSAGE 
       1 IEFC006I POSITIONAL PARAMETERS MUST BE SPECIFIED BEFORE KEYWORD PARAME
```

Comment: Why do you ask a new question for the same problem you'd asked yesterday? Did you read my answer to that Q? And, again, the JCL code you show does *not* match the JCL in the screen shot.

Comment: The *job log* you show is not from the JCL you show above it. The JCL does not have any error (provided the data sets both exist).

Answer (score 2):

The JOB statement is defined in the [z/OS JCL Manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=aip-syntax).

The first value is the accounting information and the second is the programmer information.   `3ES10G10000012'` should be in parenthesis as per the syntax information in [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=aip-syntax)

```
//TSOZA60  JOB (3ES10G10000012),'TSOZA60',MSGCLASS=Q,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),
//         NOTIFY=&SYSUID,CLASS=A,REGION=2M
```

The accounting information (the values in parenthesis) are installation defined and you may experience another issue if they do not conform to the installation requirements.

Another thing to consider is that you have two SYSIN statements.  Make the last line of your job `//` or end the file, do not leave extraneous lines or those will cause other issues.

Comment: Nope! No parenthesis. The first parm is the accounting info, the second is the programmer's name. That's two distinct parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the gentle nudge @phunsoft.  Updated to correct my error.

Answer (score 1):

The message tells you that there was an error reconized at JCL statement No. 1 (this is what the digit 1 under "Stmt No." means). The message then tells you that the parser recognized a *positional parameter* **after** having read at least one keyword parameter.

One JCL rule is that all *positional* parameters, if any, must be coded before *keyword* paramters, if any.

### Positional Parameters

Positional parameters are parameters with *no* equal sign. `3ES10G10000012`, and `'TSOZA60'` are positional parms on your job statement.

### Keyword Parameters

Keyword parameters are parameters in the form `keyword=value`. Examples are `MSGCLASS=Q`, and `NOTIFY=&SYSUID`