# JCL errors. I'm pretty sure syntax is correct, but am unsure of how to get this job submitted with no errors

Tags: jcl

I'm getting JCL error 838 and the error messages I'm seeing are: "IEFC006I Positional parameters must be specified before keyword parameter" and "IEFC001I Procedure comp was expanded using instream procedure definiti"

This is what I've typed up:

```
 //TSOZA601  JOB 3ES10G10000012,'TSOZA60',MSGCLASS=Q,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),
 //          NOTIFY=TSOZA60,CLASS=A,REGION=2M
 //COMP      PROC
 //*****
 //*****   MAKE BACKUP
 //*****
 //S1        EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY
 //SYSPRINT1 DD  SYSOUT=*
 //SYSUT1    DD  DISP=SHR,DSN=TSOZA60.ES10.CNTL
 //SYSUT2    DD  DISP=(,CATLG),DSN=TSOZA60.ES10.BACK,
 //          LIKE=TSOZA60.ES10.CNTL
 //SYSIN     DD  DUMMY
 //IFOK1     IF  (S1.RC=0) THEN
 //*****
 //*****    COMPRESS DATASET
 //*****
 //S2        EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY
 //SYSPRINT  DD   SYSOUT=*
 //SYSUT1    DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=TSOZA60.ES10.CNTL
 //SYSUT2    DD   DISP=OLD,DSN=TSOZA60.ES10.CNTL
 //SYSIN     DD   DUMMY
 //IFOKEND1  ENDIF
 //IFOK2     IF   (S2.RC=0)  THEN
 //*****
 //*****     COMPRESS SUCCESSFUL, DELETE BACKUP
 //*****
 //S3        EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
 //DD1       DD   DISP=(OLD,DELETE),DSN=TSOZA60.ES10.BACK
 //IFOKEND2  ENDIF
 //          PEND
 //FINAL     EXEC COMP
 //S1.SYSUT1   DD   DSN=TSOZA60.COPY.CNTL
 //S1.SYSUT2   DD   DSN=TSOZA60.ES10.BACK
 //S2.SYSUT1   DD   DSN=TSOZA60.COPY.CNTL
 //S2.SYSUT2   DD   DSN=TS0ZA60.COPY.CNTL
 //S3.DD1      DD   DSN=TSOZA60.ES10.BACK
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71344871/what-does-this-jcl-error-code-mean-cant-figure-out-what-i-need-to-fix ?

Comment: well no, there's an additional error message and it's a new job with entirely different code so it's not a duplicate? i'm also just learning so maybe there is some overlap in the questions, but I obviously didn't realize because I don't know everything yet...

Comment: You should have learnt by now that you should show all information you have. Please update your question and show the job's output. I doubt the job as shown throws a `IEFC006I` message. Message `IEFC001I` is just an information telling the source of the procedure referenced in the`FINAL` step.

Comment: @phunsoft that's all the information I see as far as error messages go. As previously mentioned, I'm still learning. Once I figure out how to access additional information about the job, I will be sure to update the posting

Comment: @IsabellaLovett please post the output from the job in addition to your JCL

Comment: @Isabella Lovett If this is all you see, then how do you know there is an error? How do you login into the mainframe? Using TSO/E? What else?